# How to control what fields are included in generated webservice types?

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservice-client

I am working on a legacy system, where webservice-clients were included as packaged .jar-files. We wanted to change this, to instead generate the clients. But after this was done, there were some differences, where the .jar-clients had access to all fields of the returned objects, there were some missing in the generated versions. (They were actually missing from the generated xsd of the service, and thus not generated in the client). We pretty quickly noticed that the difference between the missing fields, and the ones that were present was that the missing ones did not have both a getter and a setter. After adding these, most of the fields were included, but not the ones were the return type of the service-method was a List.

So my question is, which methods must be present in order for a field to be included in the xsd-schema of a service? And more specifically, which methods must be present for a collection to be included?

In the service-class:

```
public Organization getOrganization(final Integer id) {
    return something.getOrganization(id);
}
```

and in Organization:

```
public class Organization {
    private Integer id;
    private List<String> phoneNumbers;
    private String name;

    public Organization(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    //No setter for name, so the field is not included in the wsdl..

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //Id has both setter and getter, so it is included..

    public List<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(final List<String> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

    //phoneNumbers has both getter and setter, but still is not included. 
    //I guess it is because it is a list.
```

Comment: How are you generating your clients?

Comment: The clients are generated based on the wsdl/xsd, using a JAX-WS generator. I think I've kinda figured it out, talked to a colleague, and he told me that for lists, you don't get a generated setter, you have to call getMyList().add() to manipulate it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what teh problem was but if it's working for you then well and good! Are you saying the phoneNumbers element wasn't defined in the WSDL? What's the code you pasted above from?

Comment: The problem was that there was no setPhoneNumbers-method in the generated client, but it was in the one that was packaged as a .jar-file. So after changing the .jar-client for the generated, my code wouldn't compile. But, once i remembered that one does not really need a setter to manipulate a list, the getter is enough, then it turned out OK. The other part was figuring out what was required for a field/method to be included in the WSDL/XSD, and based on my experience the last few days I'd have to say the field itself, a getter, and a setter. But it would be nice to know exactly what..